# XML with links & VB search & delete files extention

Tags: xml, vb.net, ssis

I have an XML file that has paths to where files are kept.

```
<ROOT>
    <FILENAME>
         <LOCATION>E:\Test\</LOCATION>
    </FILENAME>
</ROOT>
```

Using this XML file, I want VB to use this link to search for *.txt, *.log, *.csv file extensions. 
Deleting code as follows.

NB: I'm scripting in SSIS.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.IO


Public Sub Main()
    Try

        For Each f In Directory.GetFiles("C:\Test\sample", "*.log", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime("C:\Test\sample").ToLocalTime()
            File.Delete(f)
        Next

    Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out...

```
Public Sub Main()

    'Declare the XML file.
    Dim xmldoc As New XmlDataDocument()
    Dim xmlnode As XmlNodeList
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim str As String
   'Get xml file and load it.
    Dim fs As New FileStream("C:\Test\sample.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    xmldoc.Load(fs)
    'Read the children. Case sensitive
    xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Area")

    For i = 0 To xmlnode.Count - 1
        xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim()
        str = xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim()
    MsgBox(str)
```

Just need to sort the deleting bit out as the output can be seen by the msgbox, I am looking for this next part...

Answer (score 0):

How to delete a file in vb.net:

```
        Try
            File.Delete(PathAndFile)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

To get the age of a file:

```
       MsgBox(System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime("c:\pagefile.sys").ToLocalTime)
```